# Use SVG. Is picture quality will not change?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

In my android project I use png to show image view.
As result in all drawable subfolders has png in all dependencies.

in

```
res/drawable, res/drawable-mdpi, res/drawable-xhdpi, res/drawable-xxhdpi, res/drawable-xxxhdpi.
```

Nice it's work fine in all devices with different screen resolution.

But what if I use ONLY ONE **SVG** (vector) file in folder one folder `res/drawable`.

Is as result also in ALL devices with different resolutions the image will be good?

Comment: yes it will work, if you have issues u can use `app:srcCompat` instead of `src:`
in ImageViews and also //For Gradle Plugin 2.0+
 `android {
   defaultConfig {
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
 }`
in your gradle

Comment: And the picture quality will not deteriorate on smartphones with large screens?

Comment: nope quality will be the same, you can use an svg to make a movie poster, be sure to set the scaleType accordingly. Open your svg in chrome and scale the window and see it wont blur

Comment: remember there are height and width attributes in xml file that is generated when importanting svg[s].

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely the picture quality will be good when you comparing with the PNG image and also the workload will be so less. When you import the SVG images it will be in the form of XML, In that XML you can change the color and size as well.
 Still, it's an XML format the picture quality is good.

Comment: So and last question. When is better to use PNGs files in all subfolders (drawable)? Why not ALWAYS use ONE FILE SVG ?

Comment: the thing about workload is definitely not true. SVG are vector images and on new android versions are rendered at runtime. If you use a complicated SVG you will degrade the performance of the app compared to when you use raster images that will have linear render time.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your point. But I suggest this for only a simple SVG vectors.